# Android save and load firstrun state

Tags: android

In my app when user clicks a button, a male or a female sound is played. I want this: if at first run a male sound was played then also at the other clicks/runs a male sound is played. So no female voice ever. If at first run a female sound was played then also at the other clicks/runs a female sound is played. I do not mean just clicking the button, i mean everytime the user opens the app.

Here is my code for randomize and playing:

```
    randNem = new Random();
    nem = randNem.nextInt(2)+0;
    NameButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    NameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
             if (nem == 0)
             {
                 mp = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.hellomyfriend_amy);   
                 mp.start();

                 mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                     @Override
                     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                         mp.release();
                         NameButton.setEnabled(true);
                     }

                 });

             }
             else if (nem == 1)
             {
                 mp = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.hellomyfriend_joey);   
                 mp.start();
                 mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                     @Override
                     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                         mp.release();
                         NameButton.setEnabled(true);
              }

                 });

             }


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to store state in your application that persists after restarting. Shared Preferences seems like an ideal fit for this.

You could do the following :

1. Check your shared preferences if a male/female voice is stored under the key PREF_VOICE.
2. If PREF_VOICE is empty, start the randomizer, and store the result (male or female) in the PREF_VOICE preference.
3. From then on, always retrieve the voice (male/female) from the shared preferences.

When you restart the app, there is no need to run the randomizer, as the PREF_VOICE will contain the voice (male/female) that was last used.

More info on shared prefs can be found here :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0):

by using shared preferences  (it will save the count)you can count the number of times  your application have been open, now for the odd fix the male  and for even fix it for female,this could solve your problem of every time your application will start then it will know which voice to play.  well i hope this could have helped you a little ,thanks